# CodeIgniter form validation does not recognise $_FILES

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, file-upload

Im using a custom form validator function to check if an image type file is being uploaded. Its quite simple, but no matter what I try I cant seem to get the validator to pass the variable correctly.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="image" /><div><?php echo form_error('image'); ?></div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function postAd(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("image", "image", "callback_valid_image");

     if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('header', array('title'=>"Post an ad"));
            $this->load->view('ads/default');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }else{
            echo "EMPTY";
        }
}

public function valid_image($file){
     echo "RAW:" . $file . "<br />";
     echo "FILE:",$_FILES[$file];
}
```

I have set up the messages in the form_validation language file too.

Regardless of what type of file I enter, or if I leave it blank, it will never show any file at echo "RAW" or echo "FILE" lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Form Validation Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) does not apply to the `$_FILES` array, only to `$_POST`. You should use the [File Uploading Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) and use something like:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else{
    //upload worked.
}
```

Comment: I would like to do something as simple as this, but I need to upload as a BLOB and not to the server itself.

Comment: @JackalopeZero: Upload is always as a file first-hand. Codeigniter does not offer that much abstraction that you could treat it as a blob.

Answer (score 0):

To set your own custom message use the following function :

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Message');
```